# Vectorize pixelwise assignment for color mapping of a segmentation mask

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, vectorization

I want to color a segmentation mask, so it is viewable by a human.

So I have a mask M[y,x,1], where every element is between 0 and n, where n is the amount of classes in the segmentation mask. Furthermore I have a colour table T[n,1,3] where I map every class to a colour in BGR. Lastly I have my colored mask image O[y,x,3] which should have the colour value (defined in T) of the class (defined in M).

I have solved it pixelwise with the following code:

```
def make_colour_mask(segment_mask):
h = segment_mask.shape[0]
w = segment_mask.shape[1]

colour_mask = cv2.cvtColor(segment_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

colour_table = [[0,0,0],[255,255,255],[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255],[255,0,255],[255,255,255]]

# loop over the image, pixel by pixel
for y in range(0, h):
    for x in range(0, w):
        colour_mask.itemset((y, x, 0), colour_table[segment_mask.item(y,x)][0])
        colour_mask.itemset((y, x, 1), colour_table[segment_mask.item(y,x)][1])
        colour_mask.itemset((y, x, 2), colour_table[segment_mask.item(y,x)][2])

return colour_mask
```

But this implementation is horribly slow. Disregard the hardcoded colour table, this can be extracted later :)

Comment: `cv2.LUT`, see [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `cv2.LUT` as suggested by @Miki.

```
def make_colour_mask(segment_mask):
    colour_table = np.zeros((256, 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    colour_table[0] = [0, 0, 0]
    colour_table[1] = [255, 255, 255]
    colour_table[2] = [255, 0, 0]
    colour_table[3] = [0, 255, 0]
    colour_table[4] = [0, 0, 255]
    colour_table[5] = [255 ,0 ,255]
    colour_table[6] = [0, 255 ,255]

    colour_mask = cv2.applyColorMap(segment_mask, colour_table)

    return colour_mask
```

Ofcourse you can drag the creation of the `colour_table` outside of this function and pass it as an argument. Also, make sure that `segment_mask` is `CV_8UC1` or `CV_8UC3`.